# Cannot copy a file (using a Stream source) and reliably get its size after operation

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream, ftp-client

I am having an issue whereby I read a file from a directory to an ftp server, and the call to copy the data returns before the data is done being written, which is causing my calling code to think the file is empty, when in reality, the data eventually gets written with the correct data. It's bizarre. It's like the copy is happening behind the scenes but my code has no control over the status. I absolutely need to make sure the data has been written before I delete the source file (otherwise we could lose important data).

Here is my code in question. Note: I am using System.Net.FtpClient to connect to the ftp server. Its OpenWrite method returns a Stream object. Also, the Transport argument you see in this function is just an object with config data (the source/destination directory/server to connect to, credentials, types of files to move etc etc). Showing this object would be redundant. The issue is in this code:

```
public static void MoveFromDirectoryToFTP(Transport transport)
    {

        using (FtpClient destinationServer = new FtpClient())
        {
            destinationServer.Host = transport.Destination.Host;
            destinationServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(transport.Destination.UserName, transport.Destination.Password);
            destinationServer.Connect();

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(transport.Host, transport.FilePattern))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(file))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    using (FileStream sourceStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        if (sourceStream.Length == 0) continue;

                        using (Stream destinationStream = destinationServer.OpenWrite(Path.GetFileName(file), FtpDataType.Binary))
                        {
                            sourceStream.CopyTo(destinationStream, (int)sourceStream.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    //this is returning zero, but a minute later i look at the server and the data is there
                    Debug.WriteLine("size after copy: " + destinationServer.GetFileSize(Path.GetFileName(file)));

                    if (destinationServer.GetFileSize(Path.GetFileName(file)) > 0)
                    {
                        File.Delete(file);   
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Helper.LogErrorToDisk(e.Message + " when processing file " + file, e.Source, e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to achieve a reliable file copy between directories and ftp servers and vice versa.

**EDIT: What I just realized is that this GetFileSize method is returning -1 within my method. I have no clue why, other than maybe it's getting some weird response from the ftp server when it tries to get the size (which I'm sure it's sending the 'SIZE' command). I wonder if it could be a server configuration? Can you configure ftp servers to not permit the retrieval of a file size? **

Answer (score 0):

Check that the destination file size equals the source file size then delete.

pseudo code..

```
while destination file size not equal to source file size
  sleep (1000ms)
end while

delete destination file
```